# Possibly off-topic: starter culture for sauerkraut?

Tags: fermentation, lactobacillus

I know I'm venturing somewhat off-topic here, but this is related to fermentation and lactic cultures, so there is at least some overlap with home brewing.

I'm about to try and make Sauerkraut. I remember my grandmother used to add buttermilk when making sauerkraut in the late 1940s. This makes sense to me, since Sauerkraut is produced by lactic acid fermentation, and starting a controlled fermentation is IMO preferable to hoping for spontaneous one.

However, these days buttermilk is pasturized (at least in our neck of the woods it is) so it will add lactic acid but not lactic bacteria.

Other than starter cultures specifically intended for that purpose (not cheap and easy to find here) what else could I use? Would [amasi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amasi) work?

Needless to say I will be keeping this well away from my homebrewing setup!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make a lot of kimchi which uses a similar process to sauerkraut, so far I've always used spontaneous fermentation without fail. The key difference between brewing beer and making fermented cabbage is that there's salt added to prevent growth of unwanted bacteria + submerging the cabbage in the brine to prevent mold.

Rather than trying to find a culture, I'd just give it a go. Cabbage is dirt cheap anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use yakult or other probiotic for some live lactobacillus to do the job.